# save file in java from getContent include new line

Tags: java, file, file-io, makefile

i'm writing to a file in java where the content is fetch using getContent, but the problem is that it ignores the new line:

ie: the input in the field is:

```
1
2
3
```

but what i get in the file is:

```
123
```

my code is:

```
 public void saveMap() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(""));
    int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile())) {


            fw.write(editArea.getText());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to open the file in **Wordpad** and check whether newline is showing correct or not. **Notepad** doesn't format most things.

Comment: This code may work for you be selecting the OS based new line, **fw.write(String.format("This is just Testing %sThis is just Testing 2", System.getProperty("line.separator")));**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you opened the file in Notepad++?

It might be because \r, \n, \r\n don't display equally in Windows (As far as I know, only \r\n displays properly)

Try changing this line:

```
fw.write(editArea.getText());
```

To:

```
fw.write(editArea.getText().replaceAll("[\r|\n|\r\n]", String.format("%n")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to save the file in accurate format and view this file in **Wordpad** first.

```
try
{
     FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile());          
     fw.write(String.format(editArea.getText().replaceAll("[\r|\n|\r\n]", "%s"), System.getProperty("line.separator")));
     fw.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```